# Convert multi nested Json to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe

```
{
"ABC": {
"A": {
"Date": "01/01/2021",
"Value": "0.09"
},
"B": {
"Date": "01/01/2021",
"Value": "0.001"
}
},
"XYZ": {
"A": {
"Date": "01/01/2021",
"Value": "0.006"
},
"B": {
"Date": "01/01/2021",
"Value": "0.000"
}
}
}
```

Current output after applying `pd.json_normalize(x,max_level=1)`

[image]

Expected Output :
Need to Convert this to pandas DataFrame

[image]

If any one can help or give some advice on working with this data that would be great!

Comment: I think you'll have to restructure your data a little bit to use the `pandas.json_normalize`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following while the js is your input dict:

```
s = pd.DataFrame(js)
ss = s.apply(lambda x: [pd.Series(y)['Value'] for y in x])
ss['Date'] = s['ABC'].apply(pd.Series)['Date']
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One of possible options is custom processing of your *x* object,
creating a list of rows:

```
lst = []
for k1, v1 in x.items():
    row = {}
    row['key'] = k1
    for k2, v2 in v1.items():
        dd = v2["Date"]
        vv = float(v2["Value"])
        row['Date'] = dd
        row[k2] = vv
    lst.append(row)
```

Note that the above code also converts *Value* to *float* type.

I assumed that all dates in each first-level object are the same,
so in the second level loop *Date* is overwritten, but I assume
that this does no harm.

Then you can create the output DataFrame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
df.set_index('key', inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
```

The result is:

```
           Date      A      B
ABC  01/01/2021  0.090  0.001
XYZ  01/01/2021  0.006  0.000
```

Although it is possible to read *x* using *json_normalize* into a temporary
DataFrame, the sequence of operations to convert it to your desired shape
would be complicated.

This is why I came up with the above, in my opinion conceptually simpler solution.