# Convert Nested DateTime json to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, json-normalize

The problem here is different than those defined in the questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21104592/json-to-pandas-dataframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388007/convert-nested-json-to-dataframe-using-json-normalize-in-python), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71108181/convert-multi-nested-json-to-pandas-dataframe). Specifically, the transformation and form of the output I want is different than any specified in those questions, and I also want a DateTime index. These differences cause the answers on those pages fail.

I have data formatted as a json like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "ABC",
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2001-06-31": {
            "1. open": "113.2000",
            "4. close": "113.8000",
        },
        "2001-07-01": {
            "1. open": "114.2000",
            "4. close": "114.2000",
        }
    }
}
```

I want the output to look be a pandas dataframe like this:

```
"Time Series (Daily)" | "1. open" | "4. close"
"2001-06-31"          | 113.2000  | 113.8000
"2001-07-01"          | 114.2000  | 114.2000
```

I wrote a function that works, but the `for` loop leaves performance wanting and I find it hard to read.

```
def convert_json_to_dataframe(all_json_data):
    json_data = all_json_data["Time Series (Daily)"]
    dates = []
    open = []
    close = []
    for key in json_data.keys():
        dates.append(key)
        open.append(json_data[key]["1. open"])
        close.append(json_data[key]["4. close"])
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        list(zip(open, close)),
        columns=["1. open", "4. close"],
        index=dates,
    )
    df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")
    return df
```

There's got to be a simpler, easier to read, higher-performing way to do this, maybe with `json_normalize` in pandas, but I can't figure it out.

---

**UPDATE AFTER ANSWERS & RESOLUTION.**
All I had to do was:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data["Time Series (Daily)"]).T
```

Pandas discovered the index and column names automatically, so I didn't need the `reset_index` portion of the answers.

The `orient` approach also worked:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_data["Time Series (Daily)", orient="index")
```

To get all the numbers as floats instead of strings, I did need the `apply` line:

```
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="coerce")
```

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Transposing a DataFrame is a very slow process. Constructing the DataFrame in the correct shape from the beginning using `from_dict` is more efficient. For example, for a DataFrame of shape (10000, 2), `from_dict` is ~4x faster than transposing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just do this?

```
pd.DataFrame(data["Time Series (Daily)"]).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {"index":"Time Series (Daily)"})
```

Output -

|  | Time Series (Daily) | 1. open | 4. close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2001-06-31 | 113.2000 | 113.8000 |
| 1 | 2001-07-01 | 114.2000 | 114.2000 |

Answer (score 1):

It seems the relevant data is only under `"Time Series (Daily)"` key, so you could get that and construct a DataFrame (use the `orient` parameter to get it in the correct shape):

```py
out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_data['Time Series (Daily)'], orient='index')
```

Output:

```
            1. open  4. close
2001-06-31  113.2000  113.8000
2001-07-01  114.2000  114.2000
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking json from an URL is the easiest way:

```
import requests
url='url from json file'
r=requests.get(url)
data=r.json()
df=pd.DataFrame(data['Time Series (Daily)']).T
df=df.reset_index('Time Series (Daily)')
```

Saying “thanks” is appreciated, but it doesn’t answer the question. Instead, **vote up** the answers that helped you the most! If these answers were helpful to you, please consider saying thank you in a more constructive way – by contributing your own answers to questions your peers have asked here.